# How to load multiple JSON files into Jade templates using Grunt?

Tags: javascript, json, templates, gruntjs, pug

I can successfully load one JSON file as a data source for my Jade templates using Grunt, similar to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267122/how-to-include-a-static-json-file-for-compilation-with-jade-and-grunt).

Now I need to load a set of JSON files from different folders inside my project so that all the data from them is accessible from Jade templates. How to do it better in context of Grunt tasks?

Answer (score 2):

You can load as many json files as you like with this method:

```
    // Jade => HTML
gruntConfig.jade = {
    compile: {
        options: {
            data: {
                object: grunt.file.readJSON('JSON_FILE.json'),
                object1: grunt.file.readJSON('JSON_FILE_1.json'),
                object2: grunt.file.readJSON('JSON_FILE_2.json'),

            }
        },
    }
};
```

And then in the Jade template you simply need to reference the object. IE:

```
    script(src= object.baseURL + "js/vendor/jquery.js")
    script(src= object.baseURL + "js/vendor/elementQuery.js")
    script(data-main="js/main", src= object.baseURL + "js/vendor/require.js")
```

I know this is being answered a bit late but for anyone who comes across this from a google search as I have, this is the answer to loading multiple JSON files into a Jade template using Grunt.js.

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine the Objects before you serve them to Jade. For this I would recommend to use Underscore.js.

Personally I would write a method to fetch the data from the files, like this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    function combineJSONFiles() {
        var object = {};

        for(var i=0; i<arguments.length; ++i) {
            _(object).extend(grunt.file.readJSON(arguments[i]));
        }

        return object;
    }

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jade');

    grunt.initConfig(
    {
        jade: {
            html: {
                src: './*.jade',
                dest: './index2.html',
                options: {
                    client: false,
                    pretty: true,
                    data: combineJSONFiles(
                        "1.json",
                        "2.json",
                        "3.json"
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('default', 'jade');
};
```

Hope that helps!