# Using Assemble, generate HTML files from multiple data files using one template file?

Tags: gruntjs, assemble

I am trying to use Assemble to generate multiple static files from multiple data files using one template.

In more detail, I have 12 JSON files representing the data for cooking recipes, and one Handlebars file, recipe.hbs, with a layout file of default.hbs.

I want to output an HTML file based on each of those JSON files.

**File Structure:**

```
/templates
    /data
        recipe1.json
        recipe2.json, etc.
    /layouts
        default.hbs
    /pages
        recipe.hbs
```

**Output:**

```
/output
    recipe1.html (based on recipe1.json)
    recipe2.html (based on recipe2.json), etc.
```

It sounds like this should be possible using collections, but I can't seem to wrap my head around how to set up the Grunt file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created this gist: https://gist.github.com/doowb/ca6f3321a05f6ac727e5
that has the code in the `Gruntfile.js` file for dynamically creating a `pages` list with the combined recipe template and the recipe data.

[These lines](https://gist.github.com/doowb/ca6f3321a05f6ac727e5#file-gruntfile-js-L7-L25) are the key to creating the `pages` array. They could be moved into another file and required in to make the grunt file cleaner.

[This line](https://gist.github.com/doowb/ca6f3321a05f6ac727e5#file-gruntfile-js-L45) adds the `pages` array to the `pages` options on assemble so they'll be built.

If you don't have any other pages to be built, use [this line](https://gist.github.com/doowb/ca6f3321a05f6ac727e5#file-gruntfile-js-L50) to set the dest without pulling in any other pages.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @doowb. I was able to check this at work and everything seems to be working great.

Comment: Using this method, would I be able to read in multiple JSON files to the `data` variable? I am trying to use one JSON for site-wide data and one for a recipe. I tried wrap two `grunt.file.readJSON()` calls in an object, but that didn't work.

Comment: I figured out how to load multiple files into `data` variable through this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/23030021/664898

Comment: If you do `data: ['templates/data/*.json']` in the assemble options, all the data files will be loaded in and available based on the file's name. e.g. `{{recipe1.something}}`

Comment: Just looking back at this question for another project, would it be possible to have each page set its own dest? I can write this in a new question if you prefer. @doowb

Comment: I figured it out. I included a path in the JSON and prepended it to the page's filename. I also set flatten to false.