# Use json as datasource for Assemble.io

Tags: html, json, assemble

Is it possible to compile json files to html using templates in Assemble.io. And if it is possible, how can I setup my gruntfile to do so?

#### My folder structure:

- Data

  - productlist1.json
  - productlist2.json
  - productlist3.json
  - productdetail1.json
  - productdetail2.json
- Templates

  - product-listing.hbs
  - product-detail.hbs
- Layouts

  - main.hbs
- Partials

  - ...

#### HTML result

I want to generate the following html files

- productlist1.html
- productlist2.html
- productlist3.html
- productdetail1.html
- productdetail2.html

#### Example productlist1.json file

```
    {
      "template": "product-listing.json",
      "products": [
        {
          "name": "product1",
          "price": "€ 2,40"
        },
        {
          "name": "product2",
          "price: "€ 1,40"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found a solution thanks to [Using Assemble, generate HTML files from multiple data files using one template file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23839023/using-assemble-generate-html-files-from-multiple-data-files-using-one-template).

Modified the example a little bit to load dynamic tamplates:

```
'use strict';
var _ = require('lodash');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = function(grunt) {

    // expand the data files and loop over each filepath
    var pages = _.flatten(_.map(grunt.file.expand('./src/data/*.json'), function(filepath) {

        // read in the data file
        var data = grunt.file.readJSON(filepath),
            fileTemplate = grunt.file.read("./src/templates/" + data.template);

        // create a 'page' object to add to the 'pages' collection
        return {
            // the filename will determine how the page is named later
            filename: path.basename(filepath, path.extname(filepath)),
            // the data from the json file
            data: data,
            // add the recipe template as the page content
            content: fileTemplate
        };
    }));

    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({

        config: {
            src: 'src',
            dist: 'dist'
        },

        assemble: {
            pages: {
                options: {
                    flatten: true,
                    assets: '<%= config.dist %>/assets',
                    layout: '<%= config.src %>/templates/layouts/default.hbs',
                    partials: '<%= config.src %>/templates/partials/**/*.hbs',

                    // add the pages array from above to the pages collection on the assemble options
                    pages: pages
                },
                files: [
                    // currently we need to trick grunt and assemble into putting the pages file into the correct
                    // place using this pattern
                    { dest: './dist/', src: '!*' }
                ]
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('assemble');

    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'assemble'
    ]);

};
```