# Dynamic YFM with single template and multiple JSON files

Tags: gruntjs, assemble

I have multiple JSON files being looped over and populating a single template as seen in this question: [Using Assemble, generate HTML files from multiple data files using one template file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23839023/using-assemble-generate-html-files-from-multiple-data-files-using-one-template)

Each one of my JSON files has a title and description - how can I load these into the template (generally done with YFM) so that each generated HTML file has a unique title and description?

Comment: I tried concatenating the YFM block as a string to the beginning of the template but that doesn't work. 
Attached the gist here: [link](https://gist.github.com/patrickng/c138c4ac8e6891fecbfc)
`console.log(concatModProjectTemplate)` shows the right format but the resulting HTML does not show the title or description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In assemble v0.4.x when you pass in the pages as a data object (like you're doing), only the `data` object is used. The data parsed out of the page content is not used.

Try updating your code to add the properties to `data` instead of concating the template:

```
// read in the data file
var data = grunt.file.readJSON(filepath);
data.title = data.project.projectTitle;
data.description = data.project.meata.description;
```

This is fixed in v0.6.x

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that it's not important for the projectTemplate to have the YFM injected up top. To get it to show up, I just modified the `data` object with the title and description.

In essence, this gist https://gist.github.com/patrickng/c138c4ac8e6891fecbfc becomes https://gist.github.com/patrickng/5d36eb9ada2d353ff98e